# ViewPager2 FragmentStateAdapter Doesn't Call onStart when Fragment is Resumed

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, android-viewpager2

I'm migrating my app to ViewPager2 and I have initializations done in onStart which I had to move to onResume for ViewPager2. Why is onStart and onStop not guaranteed to be called when re-entering a page after onPause has been called? According to the fragment lifecycle, onStart must be called before onResume. It only gets called once at three screens before entering the page.

Three pages before the page (setoffscreenlimit=3):

```
D/Fragment: ON START
```

Currently on the page:

```
D/Fragment: ON RESUME
```

Navigating backwards:

```
D/Fragment: ON PAUSE
```

Navigating back to the page:

```
D/Fragment: ON RESUME
```

Comment: If your fragments aren't getting a call to `onStop()`, why would they get another call to `onStart()`? They'd already be started.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yeah, you're right. I was referring to this illustration: https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20201112160354/AndroidFragmentLifecycle.png. According to the illustration, I thought that if the fragment goes to onPause(), then it has to go through onStop() then to onStart() to get to onResume().

Comment: That's never been an assumption you could make, no.

Comment: That diagram is incorrect, the `onResume` to `onPause` is bidirectional, as you have set the `setoffscreenlimit` to 3 then it should create the first 4 Fragments up to `onPause` and then pause or resume them, if you move from Fragment 0 to Fragment 1 it will start Fragment 5 to keep the precreated Fragments at +/- 3

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it makes sense now. I wasn't aware that the diagram was wrong